Variable frame color with tcolorbox
Well, I have made this :
\newtcbox{\inline}[1][]{
    on line,
    colback=dark4!50!dark3,
    coltext=white,
    colframe=dark3!50!dark2,
    boxrule=0.5pt,
    arc=1pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
    #1
}

But I would like to create a new command named \cframe such that when I type this in my code :
\cframe{text}
It returns the same as the \inline command. And if I type this:
\cframe[<color>]{text}
It returns the same as the \inline command, but with the colframe changed from its default definition:

colframe= dark3!50!dark2 (default definition)


to :

colframe= <color>


Here's an example


With the help of skin and \tcbsubskin to define the default list of skins, and using \NewTCBox instead of \newtcbox to use ltcmd syntax, we can define this pretty straight forward:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{dark4}{gray}{.4}
\definecolor{dark3}{gray}{.3}
\definecolor{dark2}{gray}{.2}

\tcbsubskin{pierrot}{standard}
  {%
    on line,
    colback=dark4!50!dark3,
    coltext=white,
    colframe=dark3!50!dark2,
    boxrule=0.5pt,
    arc=1pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
  }
\newtcbox\inline[1][]{skin=pierrot, #1}
\NewTCBox\cframe{o}{skin=pierrot, IfValueT={#1}{colframe={#1}}}

\begin{document}
\cframe{text}
\cframe[red]{text}
\end{document}


